# Building UI using Litho and JSON

Tags: litho, facebook-litho

I was looking for Backend Driven UI libraries for Android and came across Litho for Declarative UI. I was wondering if there is any helper/extension library for Litho that can generate the UI based on JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not smth we are aware of. But due to its declarative nature it's not hard to build one by yourself. Conceptually, you'll just need to propagate all props from json fields to Component props and a special field for a Component type.