# Dynamic UI from JSON template using Litho

Tags: android, json, dynamic-ui, facebook-litho

I am working on Dynamic screens using server-driven UI in Android. Ref to this post on [Building UI using Litho and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60281543/building-ui-using-litho-and-json/60970984#60970984). How to make use of a JSON template in Litho to render UI elements. If anyone has worked on it Please post an example.

My JSON template looks something like this

```
{
  "id":1,
  "AcceptsScan":true,
  "searchable":true,
  "sorting":"Key_column",
  "columns":[
    {
      "name":"My First Name",
      "key":"FirstName",
      "type":""
    },
    {
      "name":"EMpNo",
      "key":"EmpNo",
      "type":""
    },
    {
      "name":"EMp Department",
      "key":"EmpDept",
      "type":""
    }

  ],
  "data" :[
    {
      "FirstName":"first name",
      "EmpNo":"123",
      "EmpDept":""
    },
    {
      "FirstName":"first name",
      "EmpNo":"123",
      "EmpDept":""
    },
    {
      "FirstName":"first name",
      "EmpNo":"123",
      "EmpDept":""
    }
   ]
}
```

I wanted to create three textviews given in columns array and map the data using the "key" and generate list of data given in data array in my recyclerview.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you can add an example of your JSON payload?

Comment: @colriot I've edited my question please check